# SQL: Querying column name using value of other field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 fields in the same table:

```
cell   |    home    |    primary 
----------------------------------------------
 111        2222          cell
 456565     4654564       home
```

I would like to reach the value of either `cell` or `home` based on the value of the `primary` field.

I tried the following, which obviously does not work... but can't figure out how to convert the value of `primary` to be understood as a column name:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT primary FROM tblstudents WHERE studentid = 39358) 
FROM
    tblstudents WHERE studentid = 39358
```

Thanks

Comment: Use backticks. `\`primary\``

Comment: Or use a pivot statement and guarantee the values by limiting the rows in your Pivot statement. I don't have access to a computer right now to show you some methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT
CASE primary WHEN 'cell' THEN cell ELSE home END AS ContactNo,
primary
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` statement proposed by Sandip is the correct way.

I want to point out that you can put this directly into the table using a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE tblstudents add preferred as (CASE [primary] WHEN 'cell' THEN cell ELSE home END);
```

This has the advantage that any query using the table always uses the same logic for the preferred number.  In addition, if one of the field values change, then `preferred` automatically changes at the same time.

Note that `primary` is a SQL reserved word (think "primary key"), so it is a very bad choice for a column name.  In general, try to avoid using SQL keywords as identifiers.

Comment: Thank you - interesting idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
select primary ,
case 
    when primary = 'cell' then cell
    when primary = 'home' then home
END as phone
from tblstudents 
WHERE studentid = 39358
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you do not like the CASE selector :

```
SELECT cell phone FROM  students WHERE PRIMARY='cell'
UNION
SELECT home phone FROM  students WHERE PRIMARY='home'
```